# Udacity Sunshine app doesn't run in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I have cloned the [Sunshine sample app](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2) into my machine. I can open this app in Android Studio but the 'run app' button is inactive (greyed out). Also, I get the following errors when gradle build finishes:

> Gradle 'Sunshine-Version-2' project refresh failed
>
> Error:SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Why does this happen and how can I run the app on my machine?

Comment: I am a noob in Android Studio. I am just learning to use git too. I am sorry if this was a basic question but I have no idea about most of the seemingly simple stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the Sunshine-Version-2 repo from udacity on github. In the readme it says you need to add an API key https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/blob/sunshine_master/README.md If you haven't done that you can find instructions on the readme.

Comment: you are right, that is one of the reasons that the app was not working. Another reason was that it had the target API set to KitKat, which was not installed on my comp. So I installed the required APIs and set the developer key and it works perfectly now. Thanks for your help.